# How to implement minimized view of a form inside a div with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, plugins, animation

By default shows a minimized view inside a div,
when user click on the div,the form pop up for user to edit.

How to implement this?
Or is there a ready plugin to achieve this with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Just create it and have it small with the overflow set to hidden.

Then on click have it animate larger.

edit:

oh right. So you want it ALL to be small?

Hmm, well I don't think there is an "easy" way. What you could do it use the % on width and hight (and text size) on a search though all the compontants on the form.

Could work, that is just theory off the top of my head though.

example:

```
$("#container").click(function () {
      $(this).siblings().css({width:25%, height:25%, font-size:25%});
})
```

etc...

Comment: No,I need everything in that form to scale.

Comment: oh right. So you want it ALL to be small?

Hmm, well I don't think there is an "easy" way. What you could do it use the % on width and hight (and text size) on a search though all the compontants on the form.

Could work, that is just theory off the top of my head though.

Comment: It'll be much better if there's a ready-to-use plugin with jQuery:)

Comment: Well, I just gave a way of possibly doing it in one line (the shrinking).

Doesn't seem like a big job to me (assuming this works at all).

Comment: I don't think font size will scale with width or height of parent div:(

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right, but with a little fiddling I'm sure you'll be able to get it right!

Comment: In my case,the width and height of minimized div is specified.

Comment: Great! Then you can work out what you want it to be smaller.

(I.e design the CSS when it is small) and then just flip between two CSS objects.

Comment: var cssObj = {
        "background-color": "#ddd",
        "font-weight": "",
        color: "rgb(0,40,244)"
      }
example of a CSS object

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify a style that is bigger and one that is smaller and flip back and forth between them:

```
jQuery('#my-div').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).removeClass('smaller').addClass('bigger');
});
jQuery('#my-div').blur(function(){
    jQuery(this).removeClass('bigger').addClass('smaller');
});
```

Or something similar to that.

Comment: Yeah, he wants it for all the child elements too so this wouldn't work, but pretty much on the line I was talking to him about in the comments of my post.